# Problem loading Java applets after creating VM in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet, jvm

I have an Internet Explorer Browser Helper Object (BHO) that uses the JNI_CreateJavaVM() API to create a Java VM in the iexplore.exe process so that I can make JNI calls for my business logic.  However, when I browse to sites that try and load Java applets (e.g., http://www.javatester.org/version.html), then the applet fails to load.  If I disable my BHO, then the applets load fine.  I am running the 1.6.0_17 version of the JRE.

Can the Java applet loader attach to an existing VM in the process, or does it need to be able to create the VM itself in order to work?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but what is a BHO?

Comment: I wondered too. Since it's IE, I'm guessing "Browser Helper Object"

Comment: probably too late , but did you find a solution to the problem . I am kind of running into the same problem.